# Jquery Autocomplete only shows one result

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to show all the results of the json into the dropdown field but I can only get one result but in the console log I get all the results, Can you please take a look into the code for knowing how to do it?

The JSON format is like this:

```
"Registro": [
{
    "attributes": {
        "codigo": "000427"
    },
    "AR_DENO": "item1",
    "AR_LER": "200140",
},
...
```

And this is the jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on('keydown', '.nombre', function () {

        var id = this.id;
        var splitid = id.split('_');
        var index = splitid[1];

        $('#' + id).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "art.php",
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        search: request.term
                    },

                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: data["Registro"][0].AR_DENO,
                                ler: data["Registro"][0].AR_LER,
                                value: data["Registro"][0]["attributes"].codigo
                            };
                        }));
                    }                      
                });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {

                $(this).val(ui.item.label);                    
                var codigo = ui.item.value; 

                // AJAX
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'art.php',
                    type: 'get',
                    data: {
                        codigo: codigo
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',

                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        var id = ui.item.value;
                        var nombre = ui.item.label;
                        var ler = ui.item.ler;
                        document.getElementById('ler_' + index).value = ler;
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
    });      
});
```

Regards

Comment: can you show the code for the dropdown too? (html)

Comment: <input type='button' value='ADD line' id='addmore'>
<table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item name</th>
            <th>LER</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class='tr_input'>
            <td>
                <input type='text' class='nombre' id='nombre_1'>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' class='ler' id='ler_1'>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

Answer (score 0):

I have already got it, I had to chenge the calling method in the autocomplete function, so, so the code woudl be this one:

```
                   response($.map(data.Registro, function (item) {

                            return {
                                label: item.AR_DENO + " " + item.AR_LER,
                                ler: item.AR_LER +' '+ item.lerDeno,
                                value: item.codigo
                            };

                        }));
```